# CSS min-height based on image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, currently I'm trying to set the minimum height for some css tabled content based on the height of the picture rather than the height of the text.

In essence, my layout is like this:

```
<Image @60% width> | <Text @40% width>
```

And I'm currently using flex boxes to do this.

However, right now, when the page is resized (I cannot use static heights as it needs to be fully responsive), at a certain point the image becomes extremely small and the text makes the container huge.

I'd like, ideally, for the text to be the same height as the image at all times and, if there is overflow, for it to be scroll based.

Here's my current Jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/D7h3z/4/

I'm not averse to using technologies that are new/experimental. I am averse to using JavaScript for this as there shouldn't be a need. And if I do need to, I don't use JQuery, so please avoid that in your answers if you can.

Comment: Are the dimensions of the image fixed in all cases?

Comment: @ZachSaucier In this case they are. Though if at all possible I'd like to keep them automatically scaling with 100% of the width.

Comment: Without using flex you can do it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/u4UTE/1/). Not sure how to do it any other way...

Comment: Why do you need flex for this anyway?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I don't, actually. I was just experimenting. Your answer worked though! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

3check out the changes I made to your fiddle -- [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlakePetersen/Enjjw/2/)

Essentially, I made the inner span of description absolute positioned and then placed an overflow-y auto on it's container span. I the applied a min-height of 200px to the img container and it appears to be working as you described. Let me know if this isn't the case.

```
.description {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

.imagebox {
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.imagebox img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:200px
}

.description span {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**EDIT** Actually doesn't work 100% yet, the image doesn't maintain aspect ratio... *sad trombone*

**EDIT 2** Added in a min-width which sorta gets it there, but from a dynamic standpoint, this is far from ideal. I will give it another look later tonight.